# Glmer: output of model when scaling a continuous dependent variable

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme

I'm exploring the use of generalized linear mixed effects models with lme4's `glmer` function and I have a question regarding the scaling of independent (continuous) variables. It seems that using `scale()` within the `glmer` function results in output that corresponds to the unscaled variable. Is that right and is scaling like this the right way to scale a variable and report the results?

Here's a toy example in which 500 people that differ by Var (continuous variable ranging from 0 to 4), were tested under three different conditions (A, B, C). The probability that event Y happened during each of these three conditions was calculated from 50 trials in which event Y did or didn't take place.

````r
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)
library(emmeans)
library(ggplot2)

###Simulate some data
set.seed(558)
df <- data.frame(ID = rep(paste0("ID", 1:500), times=3),
           Type = rep(c("A","B","C"), each=500),
           Type_prob = rep(c(-0.15, 0.15, 0.4), each=500),
           Var = rep(runif(500, min=0, max=4), times=3),
           Random = rep(rnorm(n=500, mean=0, sd=0.2), times=3),
           Resid = rnorm(n=1500, mean=0, sd=0.2))

df$lp <- df$Type_prob*df$Var + df$Type_prob + df$Random +df$Resid  
df$link_lp <- exp(df$lp)/(1+exp(df$lp))

df$y <- rbinom(n=1500, size=50, prob=df$link_lp)

df$notY <- 50 - df$y
df$proportion <- df$y/50

###Run glmer with UNSCALED variable and visualize results using emmeans package
m1 <- glmer(cbind(y, notY) ~ Type * (Var) + (1|ID), data=df, family=binomial)

m1_trends <- data.frame(lstrends(m1, ~Type, var="Var", adjust = "tukey", transform="response"))
m1_Intercepts <- data.frame(lsmeans(m1, ~Type|Var, adjust = "tukey",  type="response" , at=list(Var=0))  )
m1_trends$intercept <- m1_Intercepts$prob[match(m1_trends$Type, m1_Intercepts$Type)]

#plotting shows that model predicted trends and intercept fit the data well
ggplot(df, aes(x=(Var), y=proportion))+
  facet_wrap(~Type)+theme_bw()+
  geom_point()+
  geom_abline(data=m1_trends, aes(intercept=intercept, slope=Var.trend), col="blue")

###Run glmer with SCALED variable and visualize results using emmeans package
m1s <- glmer(cbind(y, notY) ~ Type * scale(Var) + (1|ID), data=df, family=binomial)
m1s_trends <- data.frame(lstrends(m1s, ~Type, var="Var", adjust = "tukey", transform="response"))
m1s_Intercepts <- data.frame(lsmeans(m1s, ~Type|Var, adjust = "tukey",  type="response" , at=list(Var=0))  )
m1s_trends$intercept <- m1s_Intercepts$prob[match(m1s_trends$Type, m1s_Intercepts$Type)]

#plotting using scale(Var) does not fit the data well
ggplot(df, aes(x=scale(Var), y=proportion))+
  facet_wrap(~Type)+theme_bw()+
  geom_point()+
  geom_abline(data=m1s_trends, aes(intercept=intercept, slope=Var.trend), col="blue")

#plotting using (Var) shows that the output corresponds to the unscaled variable
ggplot(df, aes(x=(Var), y=proportion))+
  facet_wrap(~Type)+theme_bw()+
  geom_point()+
  geom_abline(data=m1s_trends, aes(intercept=intercept, slope=Var.trend), col="blue")

```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the model `m1s`, the differentiation is with respect to `Var`, not to the scaled version of `Var`; so, yes, the results should be the same as for `m1`. Just to illustrate, I'll show those results:

```
> lstrends(m1s, ~Type, var="Var", adjust = "tukey", transform="response")
 Type Var.trend      SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 A      -0.0289 0.00344 Inf   -0.0357   -0.0222
 B       0.0358 0.00344 Inf    0.0290    0.0425
 C       0.0704 0.00298 Inf    0.0645    0.0762

Trends are obtained after back-transforming from the logit scale 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

Suppose instead we re-scale the variable in advance:

```
> df <- transform(df, sVar = scale(Var))
> m1pre.s <- glmer(cbind(y, notY) ~ Type * sVar + (1|ID), 
+     data=df, family=binomial)

> lstrends(m1pre.s, ~Type, var="sVar", transform="response")
 Type sVar.trend      SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 A       -0.0334 0.00396 Inf   -0.0411   -0.0256
 B        0.0412 0.00396 Inf    0.0335    0.0490
 C        0.0812 0.00344 Inf    0.0744    0.0879

Trends are obtained after back-transforming from the logit scale 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

These are derivatives w.r.t. the scaled variable `sVar`.

To further elucidate this, note that

```
> attributes(scale(df$Var))
$dim
[1] 1500    1

$`scaled:center`
[1] 1.853249

$`scaled:scale`
[1] 1.153254
```

So another way to get these second results is to differentiate w.r.t. `Var/1.153254`:

```
> lstrends(m1s, ~Type, var="Var/1.153254", transform="response")
 Type Var/1.153254.trend      SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 A               -0.0334 0.00396 Inf   -0.0411   -0.0256
 B                0.0412 0.00396 Inf    0.0335    0.0490
 C                0.0812 0.00344 Inf    0.0744    0.0879

Trends are obtained after back-transforming from the logit scale 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

BTW, notice that I took `adjust = "tukey"` out of the calls. That was ignored, because the Tukey adjustment only applies to pairwise comparisons.

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense actually! So if I want to report about an analysis like this, I would use ```scale()``` within ```glmer()``` and write that the analysis was performed on the scaled variable and report the results as they are?

Comment: I can’t advise on that, other than to explain clearly whether the reported trend is relative to Var or scaled(Var)